# An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException occured in mscorlib.dll but was unhandled in user code

Tags: c#, parsing, razor

I have added properties in data content in span element in cshtml page:

```
"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign pull-right"  
                                  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
                                  data-content="@resources[Resources.lbl_HelpTxt]"></span>"
```

In static class i.e Resources.cs , we have created property:

```
" public const string lbl_HelpTxt = "lbl_HelpTxt";"
```

while running application, getting exception " An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException occured in mscorlib.dll but was unhandled in user code"

Comment: Probably you didn't add the resource in the dictionary. You need to show more on how you create and fill `resources`.

Comment: Can you explain little bit Patrick?

Answer (score 0):

If you got a static class with constants like this:

```
public static class Resources {
    public const string lbl_HelpTxt = "lbl_HelpTxt";
}
```

You can access the constant like this:

```
var text = Resources.lbl_HelpTxt;
```

To access it through an indexer, you have to add this key/value pair to a dictionary:

```
var resourcesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
resourcesDict.Add("lbl_HelpTxt", Resources.lbl_HelpTxt);
var text = resourcesDict["lbl_HelpTxt"];
```